# Using C dynamic memory functions in C++ to avoid Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, posix

I'm trying to safely recover from a segmentation fault I expect to happen. I'm trying to avoid it checking using my canAlloc() function here. When canAllow returns false, A0 (which is Ackermann's if you didn't see it) should throw an exception that I can catch in the main method. checkTable and saveInTable are both functions that use a `map<int hash, int value>` to store returns from A0.

```
    bool canAlloc(){
     bool reBool = false;
     int * memch = (int*)calloc (10000, sizeof(int));
     reBool = (memch != NULL);
     free(memch);
     return reBool;
    }


    int A0(int m, int n){
if(!canAlloc()) throw;

int reInt = checkReturnTable(m,n);
if(reInt == -1){        
    if(m == 0){
        return n + 1;
    } else if(m > 0){
           if(n == 0){
                reInt = A0(m-1,1);
           } else if(n > 0){
                reInt = A0(m-1, A0(m,n-1));
           }
    }
    saveInReturnTable(m,n,reInt);
    return reInt;
} else return reInt;
}
```

From a comment:

> In main I have a try-catch block to catch any exception `try{} catch(...){}`. As I understand it the three periods should catch any exception thrown. And as I understand, the `throw` keyword throws the exception without any specifiers, but can still be caught by the three dots.

Comment: "`throw`" ? What language is this again ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. And the check there doesn't tell you much. That you could allocate some memory at one point in time doesn't mean you can allocate memory at a different point in time.

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: You haven't indicated what the actual problem is, but I see in your throw statement you aren't specifying what you are throwing.

Comment: excuse me for not being clear. In main I have a try-catch block to catch any exception `try{} catch(...){}` As I understand it the three period should catch any exception thrown. And as I understand, the throw keyword throws the exception without any specifiers, but can still be caught have the three ...

Comment: You can produce simple analytic expressions for A(0,n), A(1, n), A(2, n).  You can fairly easily imagine the analytic expression for A(3, n); beyond that, it begins to be mind-blowing (chains of n^n^n type values).

Comment: Is there no way to gracefully recover from or avoid segmentation fault??? Thing is I fully except Ackermann to eat every thing on my machine. That is why I try using a table to save intermediate values so I don't have to calculate them over and over again. I'm trying to test a range of inputs for Ackermann to see which values cause the most damage.

Comment: Instead of trying to catch a SIGSEGV, you should be avoiding it; not only is it easier, but it makes more sense.

Comment: A(4,2) is 19729 digits long... why did I think I could do that !? yeah so, no matter what i do i can't get further than what i have. Ok thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 4):

A segmentation fault is not a C++ exception.  It is indicative of a program failure that causes the OS to send a SIGSEGV signal to your process.  You won't be able to `catch` a SIGSEGV signal directly; you'd have to set up a signal handler and ... well, it gets tricky at that point, because it is not clear that you can throw an exception from within a signal handler.

A `throw` with no exception specified rethrows the current exception; it only makes sense inside a `catch` block.

You probably get the SIGSEGV when your system is unable to extend the stack any further, probably because you've run out of virtual memory.  That means one of your function calls failed because there was no space to put its arguments or local variables or return address, etc.  There is no clean way to recover from that, which is why the system generates the segmentation fault.

If the fault was because `calloc()` could not allocate memory, you'd not get a segmentation fault; you'd get a zero return value.  And you could raise an 'out of memory' exception cleanly and synchronously when it happens.  But that isn't your problem.

Comment: Thing is after the SIGSEGV is raised, I have very few options other then to just quit the program. I can write a signal handler for this, but its not like I can print a message or anything.

Comment: Right - so you don't write a program that goes out of its way to get SIGSEGV signals.  It indicates that something has gone horribly wrong.  Not a teensy little bit wrong; fatally wrong.  When the `calloc()` fails, you don't get a SIGSEGV; you get a 0 return.  You could raise an 'out of memory' exception cleanly at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *recover* from a segmentation fault, because once the fault occurs, your program is no longer in a well-defined state, and there's no mechanism to roll back to a well-defined state, either.

A segmentation fault is always a programming error in one way or another, and you must simply avoid it. In C++, you can simply catch exceptions coming from a dynamic allocation:

```
 T * p;
 try { p = new T; }
 catch(const std::bad_alloc & e) { /* ... */ }
```

Usually there's no need to be quite that manual, though, since you would wrap your dynamic allocations inside suitable managing containers (like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`), and you should catch exceptions (not even just allocation ones) at points in your program flow where you are in a position to handle the error and continue meaningfully.

(Thanks to exceptions you should not usually need to check the result of possibly throwing functions right at the call side - that's the whole point of using exceptions.)

---

If for some reason you just want to allocate raw memory, without constructing any object, you can do it in two ways:

```
// Method #1, the C++ way:
void * addr = ::operator new(n);  // will throw std::bad_alloc on error

// Method #2, the manual way:
void * addr = std::malloc(n);
if (!addr) throw std::bad_alloc();  // throw exception manually, handled elsewhere
```

Comment: You just wrap your entire function call in a try block -- but only at a point in your program flow where you can actually respond to the error condition. There's no point catching an exception if you're just going to propagate the error.